# Why use ISO 8601 format for datetime in API instead of numeric milliseconds?

Tags: datetime, language-agnostic, epoch, iso8601

My standing point:

1. **All** datetime starts from 01 January, 1970 UTC in **all** countries.
2. **All** programming language can parse numeric to datetime object.

So my question is, why use iso8601 format for API design instead of numeric milliseconds format? I couldn't find much from googling, so some examples and links will be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Because it’s more readable (even if your time zone is not UTC). It’s a very great help in debugging.

Comment: thx for the link! can't believe that q asked just 10 days ago.

Comment: You will often be surprised. It’s a good idea to search before asking.